# Refactoring Django class-based views, clean up 18 repetitive classes.

Tags: python, django, refactoring, django-class-based-views

https://github.com/AnthonyBRoberts/fcclincoln/blob/master/apps/story/views.py

I'm a little embarrassed to admit that this is mine. But it is.

```
class FrontpageView(DetailView):
    template_name = "welcome_content.html"
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Article, slug="front-page")
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FrontpageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slug'] = "front-page"
        events = Article.objects.filter(slug="events")
        context['events'] = events
        return context
```

So this is a pretty normal class-based detail view in Django.

It's assigning a template, getting an Article object, and adding some things to the context_data.

Then I copied this class 17 times. Each time, there's a different template, and a different slug, and different stuff added to the context_data.

The idea is that there's a WYSIWYG editor for administrators to change the web content, and a user authentication system, to allow multiple people access to the site content.  Basically, a super-simple CMS, so no one has to edit html to update the site.

But I really wish I could refactor this so I don't have these nearly identical 18 classes.  Any suggestions on where I should start on this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squash all of your classes down to a single class that inherits from [`TemplateResponseMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#context-and-template-responses), as [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) does, (also check out the [`SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#context-and-template-responses)) and override its `get_template_names()` method to return the template appropriate for the current situation.

A beautiful example of this being used is in the [django-blog-zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/7863dea25557dd982a8371722a664d87ead2737b/zinnia/views/mixins/templates.py#L37) project

```
def get_template_names(self):
    """
    Return a list of template names to be used for the view.
    """
    model_type = self.get_model_type()
    model_name = self.get_model_name()

    templates = [
        'zinnia/%s/%s/entry_list.html' % (model_type, model_name),
        'zinnia/%s/%s_entry_list.html' % (model_type, model_name),
        'zinnia/%s/entry_list.html' % model_type,
        'zinnia/entry_list.html']

    if self.template_name is not None:
        templates.insert(0, self.template_name)

    return templates
```

Django will take that list of names and try each item to see if it exists in the templates folder. If it does, that template is used.

### Update

After looking at your code a little more closely, perhaps something like this:

#### In your main urls.py

```
# convert each url
url(r'^$', FrontpageView.as_view()),
url(r'^history/$', HistoryView.as_view()),
url(r'^calendar/$', CalendarView.as_view()),
url(r'^news/$', NewsView.as_view()),
url(r'^visitors/$', VisitorsView.as_view()),
...
# to just
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\d/-]+)/$', SuperSpecialAwesomeView.as_view()),
# but, put this at the end of urls list after any routes that don't use this view
```

`DetailView`, after setting the class attribute `model`, will check to see if `slug` is in the url's kwargs and if it is, it will use the slug to do a model lookup just like what you are already doing: `Article.ojects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])`

#### models.py

You could add a `type` field to your `Article` model. The type will specify what type of article it is. For example, your `ChildrenView`, `YouthView`, and `AdultView` could all have a type of `music` (since the templates are all music, I'm assuming that's how they are related).

```
ARTICLE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'music'),
    (1, 'weddings'),
    (2, 'outreach'),
    ...
)

class Article(models.Model):
     ...
     type = models.IntegerField(choices=ARTICLE_TYPE_CHOICES)
     ...
```

#### Then, in your views.py

```
class SuperSpecialAwesomeView(DetailView):
    template_name = None
    model = Article
    def get_template_names(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug', '')
        templates = [
            # create a template based on just the slug
            '{0}.html'.format(slug),
            # create a template based on the model's type
            '{0}.html'.format(self.object.get_type_display()),
        ]
        # Allow for template_name overrides in subclasses
        if self.template_name is not None:
            templates.insert(0, self.template_name)

        return templates
```

Given an article instance with a type of `music` and a slug of `ministry/children`, Django will look for a template named `ministry/children.html` and a template named `music.html`.

And if you need to do some special stuff for other views (like you will probably need to for `SermonsView`), then subclass `SuperSpecialAwesomeView`

```
class SermonsView(SuperSpecialAwesomeView):
    paginate_by = 2
    queryset = Article.objects.order_by('-publish_date')
```

Comment: This is fantastic, and worked exactly as descirbed.  I've submitted some edits to the view function, to include a return statement and the get_type_display() for finding the name of the article type, instead of the integer in the get_template_names method, and a comment about where I needed to put the new regex in urls.py

Answer (score 1):

A quick approach I would think:
Add a template field in the model with a list of predefined template choices (those can be created dynamically).
Override the default DetailView methods, override the get_template_names method to assign the proper template to the view (if not available fallback, that can be done through a try: except:).
Apart from that you can alter the View behaviour with any kind of model flags.
This way you can have a single entry point for a model, rather than defining repeatable views all over the place.
I tend to keep a FrontPageView independent from other views though, for easiness and because it serves a different purpose.
If you need repeatable context entries, consider a context processor, if you need repeatable context entries for specific views consider Mixins.

Answer (score 0):

Rarely I can find a places I need to use CBD.

You can refactor it like this:

```
def editable_page(slug):
    return {
        'context': {
            'slug': slug
        }
        'template': 'mysupertemplates/{0}.html'.format(slug)
    }

def frontpage(req):
    return editable_page('frontpage')

def chat(req):
    return editable_page('char')

def about(req):
    return editable_page('about')
```

Comment: Why would be a function based view (which is not DRY) be considered refactoring? it is an approach yet not a refactoring.

Comment: This is just a suggestion.